# Django: join two tables

Tags: django, django-models

Here's what I currently have:

```
class Sessions(models.Model):
    sessionId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Ip(models.Model):
    ipId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Affiliation(models.Model):
    affiliationId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ip = models.ForeignKey("Ip", null=False, db_column="ipId")
    session = models.ForeignKey("Sessions", null=False, db_column="sessionId")
```

Now I want to find the Sessions QuerySet which returns ipId=x. Basically this is what I'm trying:

```
Sessions.objects.filter(affiliation__ip=x)
```

Is there any way I can do this in django?

Comment: This is a many to many relationship, between Session & IP.

Comment: did you try `Affiliation.objects.filter(ip__ipId=x).select_related()`
 because each row for Affiliation has a unique row in session 
you have multiple Sessions objects which can be accessed by 
`Affiliation.session` object created after filtering

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer!

```
psobjs = Affiliation.objects.filter(ipId=x)
queryset = Sessions.objects.filter(sessionId__in=psobjs.values('sessionId'))
```

Answer (score 8):

### Refactor your code

Apologize, Please bear with me and learn from it.

> You don't have to explicitly specify the id in Django. unless your class is unmanaged. Django automatically use `id` or `pk` to refer to it.

```
class Sessions(models.Model):
    pass
```

> Model naming usually Singular `Session`.

```
class Session(models.Model):
    pass
```

> Watch out for conflict model name, `Session` is already used internally by Django `django.contrib.sessions.models.Session`. Use alternative name such as `ClientSession` would be better.

```
class ClientSession(models.Model):
    pass
```

> Use `ManyToManyField` (optional), it is just a helper to simplify your queryset.

```
class ClientSession(models.Model):
    client_source = models.ManyToManyField('IP', through='Affiliation')
```

> Use GenericIPAddressField

```
class IP(models.Model):
    address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

> You have no additional attribute in Affiliation, thus you can consider removing it.

```
class ClientSession(models.Model):
    client_source = models.ManyToManyField('IP')
```

---

## Final Model

```
class ClientSession(models.Model):
    client_source = models.ManyToManyField('IP')

class IP(models.Model):
    address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
```

---

## Answer

> Querying Session is very straight forward with the current Model.

```
x = 1 # Some ID
ClientSession.objects.filter(ips__id=x)
```

Comment: I didn't answer your question directly, but I'm trying to help you with a better alternative.

Comment: If you have any question, in the refactoring part, feel free to comment

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I appreciate it. Apart from the naming, which I will bear in mind, there is a reason why I did not use the manytomany. The "Session" class can be associated with IP or with something like say User. If I use manytomany, I will see lot of null values whenever user is not logged in. I wanted to avoid this, hence the affiliation table.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you use a related_name in Affiliation model like this:

```
class Sessions(models.Model):
    sessionId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Ip(models.Model):
    ipId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Affiliation(models.Model):
    affiliationId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ip = models.ForeignKey("Ip", null=False, db_column="ipId")
    session = models.ForeignKey(
        "Sessions", null=False, 
        db_column="sessionId", 
        related_name="affiliation_session"
    )
```

Now you can filter:

```
Sessions.objects.filter(affiliation_session__ip_id=X)
```

You can use select_related for optimization if necessary

Answer (score 2):

I want to show a report where I want customer_name, mobile_no, from Details table and status from Status table. You can see my model

```
class Details(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField()

class Status(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Details, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**Solution**

Step1: Add the following code to your view. [views.py]

```
def customer_report(request):
    status_obj = Status.objects.all()
    return render('reports/customer_report.html', {'status_obj':status_obj})
```

Step2: Add the following code at your template side [report.html]

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Mobile No</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for data in status_obj  %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{data.purchase.customer_name}}</td>
            <td>{{data.purchase.mobile_no}}</td>
            <td>{{data.status}}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi I have the same problem and I'm getting this error when I tried ur solution Field 'id' expected a number but got ''.